# Correcting TIFF image in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I'm very new to QGIS. I try to open satellite images about night lights. When I open the images in TIFFf format with QGIS 3.12, only a black image opens. Thumbnail as it looks. I adjust the symbology settings as much as I do in the picture, but it still does not happen. What should I do?

[image]

Comment: Try "Cumulative count cut" or "Mean +/- standard deviation" under Min/Max Value Settings

Comment: thank you very much it worked :)

Comment: Nice, please accept my answer with the checkbox

Answer (score 2):

Try "Cumulative count cut" or "Mean +/- standard deviation" under Min/Max Value Settings

[image]